# How to get csvHelper to write csv as text

Tags: c#, csvhelper, csv-write-stream

I have the following code

```
using (StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(savetopath))
{
    using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(streamwriter))
    {
        List<string> columns = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataColumn column in shopifyDatatable.Columns)
            csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName.ToString());

        csv.NextRecord();

        foreach (DataRow row in shopifyDatatable.Rows)
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < shopifyDatatable.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                csv.WriteField(row[i].ToString());
            }
            csv.NextRecord();
        }
    }
}
```

All works fine but field such 017825892588 ends up as 17825892588.

Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: have you used the debugger..?

Comment: What type is the column in your database and in your DataTable?

Comment: all columns are type string

Comment: so what is the problem then.. `017825892588 ends up as 17825892588` with or without the zero the value is still the same

Comment: How are you verifying the 0 gets removed? What program are you using to inspect the resulting file?

Comment: mathematically, yes! but when this is used as a upc or item id it is not the same at all and that's my problem the saved csv remove the leading 0

Comment: excel, notepad++, notepad

Comment: Corrections: notepadd++ show the zero!!!

Comment: but if i load it to shopify or elsewhere it again disapear...

Comment: That means that Shopify and Excel etc treat it as a number. I have no idea what Shopify is. For Excel, it's possible there's a technique to make it treat numbers as strings (or you could generate a real Excel file instead of CSV).

Comment: I did use EPPLUS to generate an .xlsx file and automatically read the type and generate the file corretly but not so lucky with csvHelper or any csv

Comment: and even in the xlsx that shows the leading 0, as soon as I convert to csv the leading 0's disappear...

Comment: If notepad and notepad++ are showing the zero then this isn't a real issue. The problem is that when you open CSV in Excel by default it will treat this as a "General" format, which doesn't show leading zeroes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on my machine. Full [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using CsvHelper;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string savetopath = @"C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\test.csv";
            DataTable table = new DataTable();
            table.Columns.Add("Column A", typeof(string));
            table.Rows.Add("056");

            using (StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(savetopath))
            {
                using (CsvWriter csv = new CsvWriter(streamwriter))
                {
                    List<string> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                        csv.WriteField(column.ColumnName.ToString());

                    csv.NextRecord();

                    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
                    {
                        for (var i = 0; i < table.Columns.Count; i++)
                        {
                            csv.WriteField(row[i].ToString());
                        }
                        csv.NextRecord();
                    }
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Column A
056
```

Comment: I just tested that to be clear about the typeof(string): DataTable table = new DataTable();
                table.Columns.Add("upc", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("sku", typeof(string));
                table.Rows.Add("056");
                table.Rows.Add("017036645273");
                await new ShopifyUtilities().CsvWriter(table, Path.Combine(csvDirectory.FullName, "test.csv"));  


But still end up the same without the leading 0